# «Через веси и века...»

Tags: лексика, литература

В стихотворении В. В. Набокова [«Кинематограф»](http://www.stihi-rus.ru/1/nabokov/38.htm) есть строфа:

> Утопит злого, доброго поженит,
>   и снова, через *веси и века*,
>   спешит роскошное воображенье
>   самоуверенного пошляка.

Что значит выражение *через веси и века*? Что такое *веси*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит добавить, что *города и веси* значит "всё вокруг".

Слово *веси* в выражении — "селения, деревни". Оно очень древнее, известно в памятниках русской письменности с X в. Позже расширило значение, стало называть и район, квартал города — по названию влившейся в состав его деревни. *Веси* было актуально еще в XVIII—XIX вв., а сейчас сохранилось лишь в составе выражения.

Также встречается фразеологизм *по городам и в**е**сям*, означающий "повсюду, повсеместно".

*По материалам "Русской фразеологии" А. К. Бириха.*

Answer (score 2):

Aer, ну неужели вы выражения "через города и веси" никогда не слышали?! Набоков только немного переосмыслил его.

Весь — это деревня, село. Сельский населенный пункт, говоря по-современному. В любом словаре есть.
Насколько понимаю, использовалось как гипероним для *деревня, село, хутор, выселки* и т. п.

Comment: А, точно, в словаре просмотрел) Слышал, но что-то забыл